# Check column string value over time period

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a table with the following structure:

**EDITED:**

```
    id         date           status
    1        2017-04-20        good
    1        2017-04-19        bad
    1        2017-04-18        bad
    2        2017-04-20        ok
    2        2017-04-19        ok
    2        2017-04-17        ok
    2        2017-04-16        bad
```

I need to check whether the status was the same for a period of time, let's say for the past 3 days. I tried

```
SELECT id, date CASE WHEN status over(partition by id order by date rows between 3 preceding and current row) = 'ok' THEN true ELSE false END as test FROM Table
```

The result would look like that:

```
    id         date           test
    1        2017-04-20        false
    1        2017-04-19        false
    1        2017-04-18        false
    2        2017-04-20        true
    2        2017-04-19        false
    2        2017-04-17        false
    2        2017-04-16        false
```

But it,of course, throws an error. Thank you!

Comment: logic is not clear - add in your example this row: 2, 2017-04-16, bad.  what would be output?!

Comment: My bad. Made a mistake in the description. Added the necessary row

Comment: aha, now it make more sense :o)

Comment: Hi @hamsy, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider upvoting and/or choosing an answer as this is important here in this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is for BigQuery STandard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS ( 
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE '2017-04-20' AS date, 'good' AS status UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-19', 'bad' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-18', 'bad' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-20', 'ok' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-19', 'ok' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-17', 'ok' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-16', 'bad'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  date, 
  MAX(status) OVER(win) = MIN(status) OVER(win) AND COUNT(status) OVER(win) = 3 AS test
FROM yourTable
WINDOW win AS (
  PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
-- ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

Note: this assumes you have row for each & every day so 3 days are 3 rows!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that demonstrates checking whether all statuses were the same:

```
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, DATE '2017-04-20' AS date, 'good' AS status UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-19', 'bad' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-18', 'bad' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-20', 'ok' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-19', 'ok' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-04-17', 'ok'
)
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  MAX(status) OVER StatusWindow = MIN(status) OVER StatusWindow AS test
FROM Input
WINDOW StatusWindow AS (
  PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
);
```

Note that just checking MAX isn't sufficient for certain inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, date, CASE WHEN MAX(status) over(partition by id order by date rows between 3 preceding and current row) = 'ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as test FROM Table
```

Comment: I was just about to answer my question myself. max really made the trick. Thanks anyway ;)